# Error when assigning a difference to a vector in julia

Tags: r, julia

### Goal

I have a working R function that uses a for-loop. To take advantage of julia's speed, I am re-writing the R function julia.

#### R function

```
apply_wiedemann <- function(data,
                            V_DESIRED,
                            FAKTORVmult,
                            BMAXmult,
                            BNULLmult,
                            L,
                            W,
                            AXadd,
                            BXadd,
                            angular_vel_threshold,
                            EXadd,
                            OPDVadd
){
  
  
  
  ## Parameters --------------------------------------------------------------------
  V_MAX <- 44

  L <- L

  angular_vel_threshold <- angular_vel_threshold
  CX = sqrt(W / angular_vel_threshold)

  BMIN = -8
  AX = L + AXadd 
  
  
  ## Time--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  delta_T <- (data$frames[2] - data$frames[1])/60
  last_time <- tail(data$time_complete, 1)
  Time <- seq(from = 0, to = last_time, by = delta_T)
  
  
  
  
  ## Empty vectors
  BMAX <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time)) ### an empty vector 
  vn_complete <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time))
  vn_complete[1] <- data$ED_speed_mps[1]
  
  vn1_complete <- data$LV_speed_mps
  dv <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time))
  dv[1] <- data$LV_DV_mps[1]
  
  
  xn_complete <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time))
  xn_complete[1] <- data$ED_position_m[1]
  
  
  xn1_complete <- data$LV_position_m
  
  
  bn_complete <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time))
  
  sn_complete <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time))
  sn_complete[1] <- data$LV_spacing_m[1]
  
  
  
  BX <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time)) ### an empty vector 
  ABX <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time)) ### an empty vector 
  
  SDV <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time)) ### an empty vector 
  B_App <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time)) ### an empty vector 
  
  bl <- data$LV_acc_mps2
  
  B_Emg <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time))
  
  SDX <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time))
  
  CLDV <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time))
  
  OPDV <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time))
  
  cf_state_sim <- rep(NA_character_, times = length(Time))
  
  
  
 BNULL = BNULLmult 
  
  
  FaktorV = V_MAX / (V_DESIRED + FAKTORVmult * (V_MAX - V_DESIRED))
  
  
  EX = EXadd
  
  
  for (t in 1:length(Time)) { 
    
   BX[t] = BXadd * sqrt(min(c(vn_complete[t], vn1_complete[t]), na.rm = TRUE)) ###0.8 | 0.886
    
    ABX[t] = AX + BX[t] ### 16.91 | 16.996
    
    
    SDV[t] = ((sn_complete[t] - AX)/CX)^2 ###0.34 |
    
    
    SDX[t] = AX + (EX * BX[t])
    
    
    CLDV[t] = SDV[t] * EX^2
    
    
    OPDV[t] = CLDV[t] * ((-1) * OPDVadd)
    
    
    
    if (!is.na(sn_complete[t]) & (sn_complete[t] <= ABX[t])) {
      
       B_Emg[t] = 0.5 * ((dv[t])^2 / (AX - sn_complete[t])) + bl[t] + 
        (BMIN * ((ABX[t] - sn_complete[t]) / (ABX[t] - AX)))
      
      bn_complete[t] <- ifelse(B_Emg[t] < BMIN | B_Emg[t] > 0, BMIN, B_Emg[t])
      
      cf_state_sim[t] <- "emergency_braking"
      
    } else if (!is.na(sn_complete[t]) & sn_complete[t] < SDX[t]) {
      
      if (!is.na(dv[t]) & dv[t] > CLDV[t]) {
        
    
        
        bn_complete[t] <- BNULL
        
        cf_state_sim[t] <- "following"
        
      } else if (!is.na(dv[t]) & (dv[t] < OPDV[t])) {
        
        bn_complete[t] <- BNULL
        
        cf_state_sim[t] <- "following"
        
      } else {
        
        BMAX[t] <- BMAXmult * (V_MAX - (vn_complete[t] * FaktorV)) 
        
        bn_complete[t] <- BMAX[t]
        
        cf_state_sim[t] <- "free_driving"
        
      }
      
    } else {
      
      if (!is.na(dv[t]) & (dv[t] > SDV[t])) { 
        
        B_App[t] = 0.5 * ((dv[t])^2 / (ABX[t] - sn_complete[t])) + bl[t]
        
        bn_complete[t] <- ifelse(B_App[t] < BMIN, BMIN, B_App[t])
        
        cf_state_sim[t] <- "approaching"
        
      } else {
        
        BMAX[t] <- BMAXmult * (V_MAX - (vn_complete[t] * FaktorV)) ###2.19
        
        bn_complete[t] <- BMAX[t]
        
        cf_state_sim[t] <- "free_driving"
        
      }
    }
    
    vn_complete[t+1] <- vn_complete[t] + (bn_complete[t] * delta_T)
    
    vn_complete[t+1] <- ifelse(vn_complete[t+1] < 0, 0, vn_complete[t+1])
    
    xn_complete[t+1] <- xn_complete[t] - (vn_complete[t] * delta_T) + (0.5 * bn_complete[t] * (delta_T)^2)
    
    sn_complete[t+1] <- xn_complete[t+1] - xn1_complete[t+1]
    
    dv[t+1] <- vn_complete[t+1] - vn1_complete[t+1]
    
    
    
    
  }
  

  
  sqrt(sum((head(vn_complete, -1) - data$ED_speed_mps)^2, na.rm=TRUE)/length(Time))
  
}
```

#### Data and Function Application

The `sdata` is available [here](https://uwin365-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/durraniu_uwindsor_ca/ESbUmoe-mcVAio3bJ5HZ1MsB7uUvbjjSawWDxBtlUUEsRQ?e=wiEkCV)

```
# Load data
load(file = here::here("data", "tidy_data", "sdata.Rda"))

apply_wiedemann(data = sdata,
                V_DESIRED = 30,
                FAKTORVmult = 0.02,
                BMAXmult = 0.08,
                BNULLmult = 0.25,
                L = unique(sdata$LV_length_m)[2],
                W = unique(sdata$LV_width_m)[2],
                AXadd = 5,
                BXadd = 5,
                angular_vel_threshold = 0.0001,
                EXadd = 2,
                OPDVadd = 2)
# [1] 7.667339
```

### Writing the same function in julia

I have written the following function:

```
function apply_wiedemann(df, V_DESIRED, FAKTORVmult, BMAXmult, BNULLmult, 
        L, W, AXadd, BXadd, angular_vel_threshold, EXadd,  OPDVadd)  
  
## Parameters --------------------------------------------------------------------
V_MAX = 44

L = L

angular_vel_threshold = angular_vel_threshold
CX = sqrt(W / angular_vel_threshold)

BMIN = -8
AX = L + AXadd 


## Time--------------------------------------------------------------------------
delta_T = (df[2,"frames"] - df[1,"frames"])/60
last_time = last(df[:,"time_complete"])
Time = collect(0:delta_T:last_time)

ts = size(Time)[1]

## Empty vectors-----------------------------------------------
BMAX = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)
vn_complete = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)
vn_complete[1] = df[1,"ED_speed_mps"]

vn1_complete = df[:,"LV_speed_mps"]
dv = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)
dv[1] = df[1,"LV_DV_mps"]


xn_complete = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)
xn_complete[1] = df[1,"ED_position_m"]


xn1_complete = df[:,"LV_position_m"]


bn_complete = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)

sn_complete = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)
sn_complete[1] = df[1,"LV_spacing_m"]



BX = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts) ### an empty vector 
ABX = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts) ### an empty vector 

SDV = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)### an empty vector 
B_App = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts) ### an empty vector 

bl = df[:, "LV_acc_mps2"]

B_Emg = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)

SDX = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)

CLDV = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)

OPDV = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)

cf_state_sim = Vector{Union{String,Missing}}(missing, ts)



## Unintentional Acceleration and Deceleration when the car is at V_DESIRED
# BNULL = BNULLmult * (RND4 + NRND) 
BNULL = BNULLmult 


FaktorV = V_MAX / (V_DESIRED + FAKTORVmult * (V_MAX - V_DESIRED))


# EX = EXadd + EXmult * (NRND - RND2)
EX = EXadd




for t in collect(1:1:(ts-1)) 

    #println("$t")

    ## Speed-dependent part of Minimum following distance
    BX[t] = BXadd .* sqrt(min(vn_complete[t], vn1_complete[t])) 

    ## Minimum following distance
    ABX[t] = AX + BX[t] 


    ## Speed-difference at which driver perceives that the lead vehicle is slow
    SDV[t] = ((sn_complete[t] - AX)/CX)^2 ###0.34 |


    ## Maximum following distance
    SDX[t] = AX + (EX * BX[t])


    ## Speed-difference when driver perceives that lead vehicle is slower
    CLDV[t] = SDV[t] * EX^2


    ## Speed-difference when driver perceives that lead vehicle is faster
    # OPDV = CLDV * (((-1) * OPDVadd) - (OPDVmult * NRND))
    OPDV[t] = CLDV[t] * ((-1) * OPDVadd)



    if !ismissing(sn_complete[t]) & (sn_complete[t] <= ABX[t]) 

          B_Emg[t] = 0.5 * ((dv[t])^2 / (AX - sn_complete[t])) + bl[t] + 
            (BMIN * ((ABX[t] - sn_complete[t]) / (ABX[t] - AX)))

          bn_complete[t] = ifelse(B_Emg[t] < BMIN | B_Emg[t] > 0, BMIN, B_Emg[t])

          cf_state_sim[t] = "emergency_braking"

    elseif !ismissing(sn_complete[t]) & (sn_complete[t] < SDX[t]) 

        if !ismissing(dv[t]) & (dv[t] > CLDV[t]) 

            bn_complete[t] = BNULL

            cf_state_sim[t] = "following"

        elseif !ismissing(dv[t]) & (dv[t] < OPDV[t]) 

            bn_complete[t] = BNULL

            cf_state_sim[t] = "following"

        else 

            BMAX[t] = BMAXmult * (V_MAX - (vn_complete[t] * FaktorV)) 

            bn_complete[t] = BMAX[t]

            cf_state_sim[t] = "free_driving"

        end

    else 
        if !ismissing(dv[t]) & (dv[t] > SDV[t])
            B_App[t] = 0.5 * ((dv[t])^2 / (ABX[t] - sn_complete[t])) + bl[t]

            bn_complete[t] = ifelse(B_App[t] < BMIN, BMIN, B_App[t])

            cf_state_sim[t] = "approaching"
        else
            BMAX[t] = BMAXmult * (V_MAX - (vn_complete[t] * FaktorV)) 

            bn_complete[t] = BMAX[t]

            cf_state_sim[t] = "free_driving"
        end
    end

    vn_complete[t+1] = vn_complete[t] + (bn_complete[t] * delta_T)

    vn_complete[t+1] = ifelse(vn_complete[t+1] < 0, 0, vn_complete[t+1])

    xn_complete[t+1] = xn_complete[t] - (vn_complete[t] * delta_T) + (0.5 * bn_complete[t] * (delta_T)^2)
        
   ##### Error occurs with sn_complete line 
   
    sn_complete[t+1] = xn_complete[t+1] - xn1_complete[t+1]
 #=
    dv[t+1] = vn_complete[t+1] - vn1_complete[t+1]
    =#
    #println(xn_complete[t+1] - xn1_complete[t+1])
end 

### How to do this sum? I could not find the 'sum' function in julia
#sqrt(sum((head(vn_complete, -1) - data$ED_speed_mps)^2, na.rm=TRUE)/length(Time))
    
end
```

#### Error when assigning the difference

As indicated above in the function definition, if I assign the following difference to `sn_complete[t+1]`, it throws an error:

```
sn_complete[t+1] = xn_complete[t+1] - xn1_complete[t+1]
```

But without assigning it, it does not throw any error.

#### Loading data and using the function:

```
using DataFrames
using RData
import CodecBzip2
df = load("sdata.rda", convert = true)
sdata = df["sdata"]

apply_wiedemann(sdata,
                30,
                0.02,
                0.08,
                0.25,
                unique(sdata[:, "LV_length_m"])[2],
                unique(sdata[:, "LV_width_m"])[2],
                5,
                5,
                0.0001,
                2,
                2)
TypeError: non-boolean (Missing) used in boolean context

Stacktrace:
 [1] apply_wiedemann(::DataFrame, ::Int64, ::Float64, ::Float64, ::Float64, ::Float64, ::Float64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Float64, ::Int64, ::Int64) at .\In[30]:115
 [2] top-level scope at In[31]:1
 [3] include_string(::Function, ::Module, ::String, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1091
```

### Questions:

1. How can I fix the `sn_complete[t+1]` line?
2. How can I do the sum (see the commented out part in function
   definition)? I could not find any `sum` function in julia.

Comment: 1. The error is commonly seen when operator precedence is not working the way you expected. I'd make sure all the expressions are doing what you expect them to do. I don't think it would be produced by the assignment line. Also check how "missing" interacts with comparison operators: `missing < 0` evalutes to `missing`, instead of a boolean, for example.

Comment: 2. Not sure what you mean, `sum` does exist. What does it tell you when you try that line?

Comment: @NickBauer I get `MethodError: objects of type Int64 are not callable` with `sum(1,1)`. But `sum([1,1])` works. So, this solves question 2. Thanks.

Comment: `?sum` shows the documentation, which shows it takes an array argument.

Comment: If you want some nicer ability to work with missing values, you might check out https://github.com/JuliaData/Missings.jl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I do not see a problem with the line that you indicated. The `TypeError: non-boolean (Missing) used in boolean context` occurs because of line 115 of your function:           `bn_complete[t] = ifelse(B_Emg[t] < BMIN | B_Emg[t] > 0, BMIN, B_Emg[t])`

There is some operator precedence issues and issues with using missing. I believe this may be closer to what you intend.

```
          predicate = ( B_Emg[t] < BMIN ) | ( B_Emg[t] > 0 )
          bn_complete[t] = ifelse(ismissing(predicate) || predicate, BMIN, B_Emg[t])
```

2. Nick answered this in part. You can find the documentation for sum here:
   https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.sum

For the last step, I created three separate versions. The first does one step per line. Note the use of the `.` to broadcast operations across an array. I believe what you want is `skipmissing` for the `na.rm = true` option but you may also want `x->filter(!isnan, x)`. `skipmissing` treats any `missing` values as `0` for the `sum`.

```
# One step per line
vn_complete_difference = vn_complete .- df["ED_speed_mps"]
vn_complete_difference_squared = vn_complete_difference.^2
vn_complete_difference_squared_sum = sum( skipmissing( vn_complete_difference_squared ) )
vn_complete_difference_squared_sum_div_length = vn_complete_difference_squared_sum / length(Time) # Did you want to calculate the mean?
vn_complete_difference_squared_sum_div_length_sqrt = sqrt( vn_complete_difference_squared_sum_div_length )

# In one line
one_liner = sqrt( sum( skipmissing( ( vn_complete .- df["ED_speed_mps"] ).^2 ) ) / length(Time) )
alt_one_liner  = ( vn_complete .- df["ED_speed_mps"] ).^2 |> skipmissing |> sum |> x->x/length(Time) |> sqrt
```

I modified your full function as follows.

```
function apply_wiedemann(df, V_DESIRED, FAKTORVmult, BMAXmult, BNULLmult, 
        L, W, AXadd, BXadd, angular_vel_threshold, EXadd,  OPDVadd)  
  
## Parameters --------------------------------------------------------------------
V_MAX = 44

L = L

angular_vel_threshold = angular_vel_threshold
CX = sqrt(W / angular_vel_threshold)

BMIN = -8
AX = L + AXadd 


## Time--------------------------------------------------------------------------
delta_T = (df[2,"frames"] - df[1,"frames"])/60
last_time = last(df[:,"time_complete"])
Time = collect(0:delta_T:last_time)

ts = size(Time)[1]

## Empty vectors-----------------------------------------------
BMAX = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)
vn_complete = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)
vn_complete[1] = df[1,"ED_speed_mps"]

vn1_complete = df[:,"LV_speed_mps"]
dv = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)
dv[1] = df[1,"LV_DV_mps"]


xn_complete = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)
xn_complete[1] = df[1,"ED_position_m"]


xn1_complete = df[:,"LV_position_m"]


bn_complete = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)

sn_complete = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)
sn_complete[1] = df[1,"LV_spacing_m"]



BX = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts) ### an empty vector 
ABX = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts) ### an empty vector 

SDV = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)### an empty vector 
B_App = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts) ### an empty vector 

bl = df[:, "LV_acc_mps2"]

B_Emg = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)

SDX = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)

CLDV = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)

OPDV = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, ts)

cf_state_sim = Vector{Union{String,Missing}}(missing, ts)



## Unintentional Acceleration and Deceleration when the car is at V_DESIRED
# BNULL = BNULLmult * (RND4 + NRND) 
BNULL = BNULLmult 


FaktorV = V_MAX / (V_DESIRED + FAKTORVmult * (V_MAX - V_DESIRED))


# EX = EXadd + EXmult * (NRND - RND2)
EX = EXadd




for t in collect(1:1:(ts-1)) 

    #println("$t")

    ## Speed-dependent part of Minimum following distance
    BX[t] = BXadd .* sqrt(min(vn_complete[t], vn1_complete[t])) 

    ## Minimum following distance
    ABX[t] = AX + BX[t] 


    ## Speed-difference at which driver perceives that the lead vehicle is slow
    SDV[t] = ((sn_complete[t] - AX)/CX)^2 ###0.34 |


    ## Maximum following distance
    SDX[t] = AX + (EX * BX[t])


    ## Speed-difference when driver perceives that lead vehicle is slower
    CLDV[t] = SDV[t] * EX^2


    ## Speed-difference when driver perceives that lead vehicle is faster
    # OPDV = CLDV * (((-1) * OPDVadd) - (OPDVmult * NRND))
    OPDV[t] = CLDV[t] * ((-1) * OPDVadd)



    if !ismissing(sn_complete[t]) & (sn_complete[t] <= ABX[t]) 

          B_Emg[t] = 0.5 * ((dv[t])^2 / (AX - sn_complete[t])) + bl[t] + 
            (BMIN * ((ABX[t] - sn_complete[t]) / (ABX[t] - AX)))

          # CHANGED THE FOLLOWING TWO LINES
          predicate = ( B_Emg[t] < BMIN ) | ( B_Emg[t] > 0 )
          bn_complete[t] = ifelse(ismissing(predicate) || predicate, BMIN, B_Emg[t])

          cf_state_sim[t] = "emergency_braking"

    elseif !ismissing(sn_complete[t]) & (sn_complete[t] < SDX[t]) 

        if !ismissing(dv[t]) & (dv[t] > CLDV[t]) 

            bn_complete[t] = BNULL

            cf_state_sim[t] = "following"

        elseif !ismissing(dv[t]) & (dv[t] < OPDV[t]) 

            bn_complete[t] = BNULL

            cf_state_sim[t] = "following"

        else 

            BMAX[t] = BMAXmult * (V_MAX - (vn_complete[t] * FaktorV)) 

            bn_complete[t] = BMAX[t]

            cf_state_sim[t] = "free_driving"

        end

    else 
        if !ismissing(dv[t]) & (dv[t] > SDV[t])
            B_App[t] = 0.5 * ((dv[t])^2 / (ABX[t] - sn_complete[t])) + bl[t]

            bn_complete[t] = ifelse(B_App[t] < BMIN, BMIN, B_App[t])

            cf_state_sim[t] = "approaching"
        else
            BMAX[t] = BMAXmult * (V_MAX - (vn_complete[t] * FaktorV)) 

            bn_complete[t] = BMAX[t]

            cf_state_sim[t] = "free_driving"
        end
    end

    vn_complete[t+1] = vn_complete[t] + (bn_complete[t] * delta_T)

    vn_complete[t+1] = ifelse(vn_complete[t+1] < 0, 0, vn_complete[t+1])

    xn_complete[t+1] = xn_complete[t] - (vn_complete[t] * delta_T) + (0.5 * bn_complete[t] * (delta_T)^2)
        
   ##### Error occurs with sn_complete line 
   
    sn_complete[t+1] = xn_complete[t+1] - xn1_complete[t+1]
 #=
    dv[t+1] = vn_complete[t+1] - vn1_complete[t+1]
    =#
    #println(xn_complete[t+1] - xn1_complete[t+1])
end 

# For diagnostics
# return vn_complete, Time, df

### How to do this sum? I could not find the 'sum' function in julia
#sqrt(sum((head(vn_complete, -1) - data$ED_speed_mps)^2, na.rm=TRUE)/length(Time))

# One step per line
vn_complete_difference = vn_complete .- df["ED_speed_mps"]
vn_complete_difference_squared = vn_complete_difference.^2
vn_complete_difference_squared_sum = sum( skipmissing( vn_complete_difference_squared ) )
vn_complete_difference_squared_sum_div_length = vn_complete_difference_squared_sum / length(Time) # Did you want to calculate the mean?
vn_complete_difference_squared_sum_div_length_sqrt = sqrt( vn_complete_difference_squared_sum_div_length )

# return vn_complete_difference_squared_sum_div_length_sqrt

# In one line
one_liner = sqrt( sum( skipmissing( ( vn_complete .- df["ED_speed_mps"] ).^2 ) ) / length(Time) )
alt_one_liner  = ( vn_complete .- df["ED_speed_mps"] ).^2 |> skipmissing |> sum |> x->x/length(Time) |> sqrt
@info "step by step", vn_complete_difference_squared_sum_div_length_sqrt
@info "one liner", one_liner
@info "alt one liner", alt_one_liner
@assert vn_complete_difference_squared_sum_div_length_sqrt == one_liner
@assert alt_one_liner == one_liner

return one_liner
    
end
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if I can clarify.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have now added an `if` statement at the beginning of the loop to address the missing values explicitly.